# Return value of fitdistr function explanation

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following generated dataset

```
library(MASS)    
df <- data.frame(product= sample(x= c("toyota","honda","nissan","bmw"),size = 1000 ,replace = TRUE),
                  parameter = sample(x= c("X","Y", "A"),size = 1000 ,replace = TRUE),
                  value= rgamma(1000, shape = 5, rate = 0.1))
```

and I want to fit the lognormal distribution on column "value" and
I use the following code

```
dist_par <- fitdistr(unlist(df["value"]), "lognormal")
```

the result is something like below:

```
  meanlog    sdlog 
  3.8416    0.4292 
 (0.0458)  (0.0324)
```

I have two questions:

1. I read the help and I guess that the meanlog and sdlog estimations are shown on the first row:

> ```
>   meanlog    sdlog 
>   3.8416    0.4292
> ```

but the second row of numbers (numbers in parentheses) are confusing, what are they?

```
  meanlog    sdlog 
 ....       ....
 (0.0458)  (0.0324)
```

2. I know the result of fitdistr is a list but I don't know how to have access to those four values. For instance how can I get `3.8416` ?

If I run

```
dist_par[1]
```

then I get

> ```
>   meanlog   sdlog 
>   3.842   0.429
> ```

and if I run:

```
dist_par[1,1]
```

then I get the following error:

```
Error in dist_par[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `?fitdistr` documentation

> An object of class "fitdistr", a list with four components,

> estimate  - the parameter estimates,

> sd - the estimated standard errors,

> vcov  - the estimated variance-covariance matrix, and

> loglik - the log-likelihood.

This would be evident if we check the `str`ucture

```
 str(out)
List of 5
 $ estimate: Named num [1:2] 3.801 0.455
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "meanlog" "sdlog"
 $ sd      : Named num [1:2] 0.0144 0.0102
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "meanlog" "sdlog"
 $ vcov    : num [1:2, 1:2] 0.000207 0 0 0.000103
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "meanlog" "sdlog"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "meanlog" "sdlog"
```

i.e. the print method returns the 'estimatte and inside the parentheses the `sd` and as they are `list` the `[1,1]` doesn't work, we need to use standard extraction methods i.e. either `$` or `[[`

```
> out
    meanlog       sdlog   
  3.80075311   0.45468543 
 (0.01437842) (0.01016708)
> out$estimate
  meanlog     sdlog 
3.8007531 0.4546854 
> out$estimate[["meanlog"]]
[1] 3.800753
> out$sd
   meanlog      sdlog 
0.01437842 0.01016708
```

i.e inside the `list`, the elements are just named vectors, so use the `[` or `[[` to extract by name